# Grails: Page won't redirect after completed Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails

This is my ajax call: `<body onload =  "${remoteFunction(controller:'accountManagement', action:'createAccount', 
        params:[facebookUID: params.facebookUID, gender: params.gender, firstName: params.firstName, lastName: params.lastName])}">`

In my controller I have a redirect instruction at the end:

```
def createAccount = {

    if(user.save(flush:true) == null){
        ... 
    }
    else{
        ....

        for(int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
            ...
        }

        println "save to database: successful"

    }

    // Redirect to index action of person controller.
    redirect(controller:'user', action: 'authenticate');


}
`
```

It does not redirect. Instead, it stays on the same loading page that it started on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers won't redirect if an AJAX call returns a redirect.  If you want to send the user to a new page after an AJAX call, you'll need to do so yourself in Javascript.  Example:

```
def url = createLink(controller: 'user', action: 'authenticate')
render(contentType: 'text/html', text: "<script>window.location.href='$url'</script>")
```

Ensure the AJAX response gets rendered by the browser.  With the grails [`remoteFunction`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) tag you should specify an element to update with the `update` attribute.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work for me, how is the script block suppose to be executed?

Comment: Are you rendering the AJAX response in the browser?

Comment: Ah, with the remote function part it makes sense, thanks for updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting the ajax call only redirects that call, not the whole page. To get the whole page to redirect, you either need to capture the redirected ajax call in the JavaScript and do a redirect from the JavaScript, or you need to have the page-level action do the redirect.

Comment: What do you mean by page-level action redirect?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon, by "page-level", I mean a controller action that is hit by a call from the page (ie. a normal link), rather than an AJAX call. The major distinction being how the browser deals with the response, either refreshing the whole screen, as with a normal page request, or handing the final result of the request off to a JavaScript handler, as with an AJAX call.