# can this be achieved with formRemote and one gsp?

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I have create.gsp for creating domain objects. Besides normal html body and headers I have two div's. One for displaying command object errors and one for data. I want to submit the form with AJAX. When I submit the form with

```
<g:formRemote name="formName" update="errorsDiv" url="[controller:myController',       action:'checkAndForward']">
```

this gets called:

```
def checkAndForward= {CmdObject p ->        

    if (p.hasErrors()) {                            

       render(template:"/error",params:params,model :[p:p])
    } else {
    forward controller: "test", action: "save", params:params

    }
}

def save = {

    id=myservice.getData()
    render(view: "show", id:id)
}
```

This is working and the save action is called in the controller but ..

The problem is that after 'save' action 'show.gsp' is displayed into where errors div is located.

I would like to have only 'show' page refreshed as if I was calling /save from browser (with posted params of course)

Comment: So what I want to do is to check for parameters using AJAX and CommandObject without touching actual form values. If the parameters are correct then call controller action and render a new page (not only one div).

Comment: Ok, found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377142/grails-page-wont-redirect-after-completed-ajax-call -->